# error while passing JSON from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

So I have this php file which have query thats extract data from the DB to draw it on a Chart **(Note : I'm using Chart.js lib)**, btw the chart working fine but in order to pass the value to the chart I have to use `json_encode()` built-in function to move the array to the **javascript** side using **AJAX** to display the array value in the chart but I'm getting this error in the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0DZH.png

My PHP code : https://pastebin.com/tNh18qGX

My HTML & JS code : https://pastebin.com/06k9xbe8

Thank you guys.

Comment: Please post a [mre] here, not as a link to pastebin.

Comment: You have a bunch of `-->` with no matching `<!--`

Comment: Is the PHP link `test.php`? It's outputting HTML before and after the JSON.

Comment: It has to output ONLY the JSON, not anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that when you go to you're .php file the only value/text/anything displayed on the page is the json u want to be retrieve by the request.